# Azure login in KUDU console

Tags: azure, kudu, azure-cli

I have an azure site, and im trying to automate UI testing and a site switch on successful UI tests. However im having some trouble logging into my azure site to do the deploy.

Inside the KUDU I have tried the following:

```
npm install azure-cli -g 
azure login -u [username] -p [password]
```

but I get the following error:

```
info:    Executing command login
warn:    Please note that currently you can login only via Microsoft organizational account or service principal. For instructions on how to set them up, please read http://aka.ms/Dhf67j.
info:    Authenticating...
error:   Credentials have expired, please reauthenticate
info:    Error information has been recorded to D:\home\.azure\azure.err
error:   login command failed
```

Executing the same on my local box works fine.

Ideally I wouldn't have to login at all in the context of a deployment but it appears I have to.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about creating a Service Principal account? David Ebbo has a great walk through (for automating a CI process) on this blog: "[Automating Azure on your CI server using a Service Principal](http://blog.davidebbo.com/2014/12/azure-service-principal.html)"

Comment: I dont think this will work inside of KUDU as it doesnt seem to have the powershell tools for azure and I dont know of any way to install them